# Splitting up measurement into multiple measurements in InfluxDB for memory performance? E.g., one measure per stock ticker for financial price data

Tags: database, influxdb, nosql

We have a massive amount of sub-minute stock price tick data stored in a InfluxDB instance on a 32 GB (memory) server, with plenty of storage. Unfortunately we are having memory issues. The following tuning has been done:

```
cache_snapshot_memory_size         => 6553600,
cache_snapshot_write_cold_duration => '1m',
max_series_per_database            => 10000000,
cluster_write_timeout              => '10s',
```

The number of series is about 650000, and almost not growing.

Simplified, our schema currently stores bid and ask prices in a single measurement `orderbook` with (non-indexed) fields like `bid`, `ask`, `bid_volume`, `ask_volume`, etc., in addition to a few (indexed) tags. All have small cardinality except one, the `ticker` tag.

Would we see a lowered memory footprint if we had one orderbook measurement per ticker? `orderbook.aapl`, `orderbook.googl`, `orderbook.abc`, etc.

For the moment we have about 300 tickers, but this can grow to as much as 10000 in a few years.

When retrieving data we always use a filter on the ticker.

References:

- Argues for not storing data in the measures, but due to how hard it is to write queries. Memory perforamnce is of essence to us: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.1/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/
- Splits up on "account" due to memory perforamnce, but it's an old blog entry: http://www.ryandaigle.com/a/time-series-db-design-with-influx

Answer (score 2):

Answers from #influxdb at [gophers.slack.com](http://gophers.slack.com):

- The method you are proposing there is non-performant. We HIGHLY advise the use of tags. That is the way the database assumes users will model their data. Adding metadata to measurements is an antipattern
- splitting up the unique tags into unique measurements shouldn't help your memory consumption significantly